# Inconsistent results from attempting to count matching values in lists within data frames in R

Tags: r, missing-data, descriptive-statistics

Pretty new to R and to stackexchange.  My apologies if I make any faux pas.

I'm working with the North Carolina births data from irss.unc.edu.  I have a data frame `NCBIRTH1450` with several lists, all of which have numeric or NA values.  I'm just trying to calculate some proportions from the data.  For one of the lists, I'm able to get the proportion of male babies by using

```
pBoyBaby <- sum(SEX==1)/sum(!is.na(SEX))
```

The above returns a numeric value for `pBoyBaby`.  My aim is to take the number of matching values and divide by the number of non-missing values, and I get an appropriate result.

However, when I attempt the same function on another column of the same type,

```
pMomSmokes <- sum(SMOKE==1)/sum(!is.na(SMOKE))
```

The object `pMomSmokes` takes the value `NA`.  How could I identify the difference between the natures of `SMOKE` and `SEX`, for instance, that explain this discrepancy?  I really don't know why it's doing this.

In case it's relevant, `SEX` has values of either `1` or `2` -- with no `NA`'s -- while `SMOKE` has the values `0` or `1`, with a few `NA`'s.

Thanks!

Comment: probably should be moved to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Peter IMHO, this is a border case: handling of NA/Null/Nodata values is of general interest in statistical analysis.  There appear to be some lessons in this example that apply beyond only `R` applications (even though at present that good stuff is found primarily in comments :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix your immediate problem by adding na.rm=T, as in

```
pMomSmokes <- sum(SMOKE==1, na.rm=T)/sum(!is.na(SMOKE))
```

The issue is the sum() function - read the help file ?sum to see why. If there are any NAs in the vector fed to sum it returns an NA. When an element in SMOKE is NA then that same element of SMOKE==1 will also be NA (because if R doesn't know what SMOKE is, it also doesn't know if it equals 1).

More generally you might want to look at the functions table() and prop.table().

Also, with R you need to be careful about what you call a "list" - you actually have vectors I think.  A list is something a bit different.  See the very useful [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) site for a good explanation, or any of the introductory material on CRAN.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I take it the == does not exclude NAs?

Comment: Yes. The issue is the sum() function - read the help file ?sum to see why.  If there are any NAs in the vector fed to sum it returns an NA.  When an element in SMOKE is NA then that same element of SMOKE==1 will also be NA (because if R doesn't know what SMOKE is, it also doesn't know if it equals 1).

Comment: @dubhousing: == is not doing what you think it's doing. Try doing `SMOKE==1` and see what the result is. As Peter Ellis says, the == is doing a reasonable thing -- not what you're thinking it does, though -- and the issue arises in `sum`. That's a helpful tip: if a  statement isn't working as you expect, try the individual pieces to see where perhaps it's working differently.

Comment: Thanks very much Wayne.  I wasn't certain as to how reducible the components of code were but based on your suggestion I can see how valuable that will be.